# Comments in freemarker template and smooks

Tags: java, freemarker, smooks

I am working on a freemarker template and here is a sample.

```
<Grantor>
    <UniqueID>${(currentGrantorIndex)!?string}</UniqueID> // want to comment this line
    <Entity>${(grantor.entityTypeName)!?string}</Entity>
</Grantor>
```

I want to know how to write comments or comment out few lines in freemarker templates. Any idea?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Comment in freemarker are delimited by `<#--` and `-->`. Everything between these delimiters will not be interpreted by freemarker and won't appear in the output.

```
<Grantor>
    <#-- <UniqueID>${(currentGrantorIndex)!?string}</UniqueID> -->
    <Entity>${(grantor.entityTypeName)!?string}</Entity>
</Grantor>
```

See freemarker reference [here](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another non-standard way of adding comments in freemarker using the if tag:

```
<#if 1=0>comment</#if>
```

or

```
<#if false>comment</#if>
```